# Why does azure search throw IndexBatchException with no failures in IndexingResults

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

In my microservice (responsible for feeding data into azure search instance based on events messages), I am trying to MergeOrUpload an IndexBatch. The batch size is always 1 as one event message only contain one entity that I need to merge or upload in search.

I am consistently getting IndexBatchException that contains no IndexingResults where Succeeded is false.

### Azure Search Service Details

- *Tier*: Standard
- *Partitions and Replicas*: 3 & 3

### Microservice details

- *Asp .Net Core version*: 2.2
- *Microsoft.Azure.Search SDK Version*: 9.0.1

Currently my code is setup to handle IndexBatchException by re-queuing the message on service bus with schedule delivery in future ~5 seconds. Upon receipt of this re-queued message, my code reject processing this event message as it finds that message date time is not later than data in search instance.

I realize I can change the exception handling to only retry if there is IndexingResults with failure but I would like to understand **the real reason behind IndexBatchException that contains no IndexingResults where Succeeded is false as well as what would community propose to do.**. Note that the operation itself was successful as data gets uploaded every time on first attempt itself.

I can also confirm that azure search instance is not under load and has not exceeded any of its limits.

### Code Sample

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public async Task ProcessDocument(DomainEvent<TMessage> domainEvent)
{
    Guard.IsNotNull(domainEvent, nameof(domainEvent));

    var searchIndexClient = await searchIndexClientFactory.CreateAsync(
        domainEvent.TenantId,
        IndexName);

    var storedDocument = await GetDocument(
            searchIndexClient,
            domainEvent);

    if (storedDocument != null && ValidateEventDate(domainEvent, storedDocument))
    {
        logger.LogWarning($"Received event but detected that more recent updates have already been applied. Incoming Event Details: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domainEvent)}");
        return;
    }

    var newDocument = mapper.Map<TDocumentIndex>(domainEvent.Resource);

    SetSomeProperties(domainEvent, newDocument); // Changed method name. It basically is adding some contextual prop's to doc

    try
    {
        var documents = new TDocumentIndex[] { newDocument };

        var batch = IndexBatch.MergeOrUpload(documents);

        var result = await searchIndexClient
            .Documents
            .IndexAsync(batch);

        var operationResult = result
            .Results
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (operationResult == null || operationResult.Succeeded == false)
        {
            logger.LogError($"There was an error when merging or uploading a document for tenant {domainEvent.TenantId}. Error message {operationResult?.ErrorMessage}, Message body {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domainEvent)}");
        }
    }
    catch (IndexBatchException indexBatchException)
    {
        logger.LogError($"Failed to index some of the documents: {0}", string.Join(", ", indexBatchException.IndexingResults.Where(r => !r.Succeeded).Select(r => $"{r.Key}:{r.ErrorMessage}")));
        throw;
    }
}
```

### Sample error log

- Failed to index some of the documents: 0
  The above is produced by following code line

```
catch (IndexBatchException indexBatchException)
    {
        logger.LogError($"Failed to index some of the documents: {0}", string.Join(", ", indexBatchException.IndexingResults.Where(r => !r.Succeeded).Select(r => $"{r.Key}:{r.ErrorMessage}")));
        throw;
    }
```

I expect to only hit index batch exception when search is under load and even if so, I expect it to throw this exception with some failed results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is returning the IndexingResults as expected, but you have a small bug in your code.  The hint of the bug is in the "0" that is being returned in "Failed to index some of the documents: 0".  If the code was functioning as expected it would be an empty string.  You need to remove the $ on the string which is evaluating the {0} as a c# expression rather than a string formatting token.

It should read:

```
logger.LogError("Failed to index some of the documents: {0}", string.Join(", ", indexBatchException.IndexingResults.Where(r => !r.Succeeded).Select(r => $"{r.Key}:{r.ErrorMessage}")));
```

Comment: Thanks Corom for your feedback. After logging fix, we realized that the error is 409 Conflict that search service throws after 1 attempt at merge that failed due to concurrency controls. Retry was successful and documents added to search as expected.